# Java: Math.random() Max Value (double just less than 1)

Tags: java, math, random, double, precision

I've been a little curious about this. Math.random() gives a value in the range [0.0,1.0). So what might the largest value it can give be? In other words, what is the closest double value to 1.0 that is less than 1.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java uses 64-bit [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) representation, so the closest number smaller than one is theoretically `3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal representation, which is 0 for sign, -1 for the exponent, and 1.9999999999999997 for the 52-bit significand. This equals to roughly `0.9999999999999998`.

References: [IEEE-754 Calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/).

Comment: What about 0.9999999999999999? it has the same number of digits, but has a 9 instead of an 8 on the end. When I `System.out.println(0.9999999999999999 - 0.9999999999999998)`, I get: 1.1102230246251565E-16

Comment: @gangqinlaohu The last digit is not precise. I truncated the number that I got from the IEEE-754 calculator (see the link in the answer) to get the number. The next digit after 8 is also 8, so if you apply rounding, the result becomes 0.9999999999999999.

Comment: Oh, so 0.9999999999999999 is closer than 0.9999999999999998, because 0.9999999999999998 is truncated, so the Double closest to 1 is 0.9999999999999999.

Answer (score 5):

The number that you want is returned by `Math.nextAfter(1.0, -1.0)`.

The name of the function is somewhat of a misnomer.  `Math.nextAfter(a, 1.0)` returns the least double value that is greater than `a` (i.e., the next value after `a`), and `Math.nextAfter(a, -1.0)` returns the greatest value that is less than `a` (i.e., the value *before* `a`).

Note:  Another poster said, `1.0-Double.MIN_NORMAL`.  That's wrong.  `1.0-Double.MIN_NORMAL` is exactly equal to 1.0.

Comment: Even better: `Math.nextDown(1.0)` - it's clearer, and possibly faster.

Answer (score -3):

The smallest positive value of a double is [`Double.MIN_NORMAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL). So, the largest number less than 1.0 is `1.0-Double.MIN_NORMAL`.

`Double.MIN_NORMAL` is equal to 2<sup>-1022</sup>, so the answer is still *extremely* close to 1.0. You'd have to print the value of `1.0-Double.MIN_NORMAL` to 308 decimal places before you could see anything but a 9.

Comment: Odd, when I encase `1.0 - Double.MIN_NORMAL == 1.0` in a System.out.println, I get true. But when I encase 0.9999999999999999 in the System.out.println, I get false. So does that mean that 0.9999999999999999 is the closest double to one?

Comment: Hum... Not, so,  MIN_NORMAL applies to the value _closest to zero_  It is of sorts the smallest error possible on IEEE-754 values. But since you moved towards 1, some of the precision gets lost!

Comment: `System.out.println(Double.MinNormal)` gives 2.2250738585072014E-308. Pretty small.

Comment: Interesting. @dasblinkenlight is correct above and I'm wrong. Intuitively, this answer is wrong because you're "spending" your precision too low to be captured in the difference between `1.0` and `Double.MIN_NORMAL`, and so the difference is "lost." Just goes to show how confusing floating-point arithmetic is. Leaving the answer and this (non-technical) explanation for posterity.

Comment: Seems to me that 0.9999999999999999 is the closest number. (found it via trial and error). When I take 0.99999999999999991 - 0.9999999999999999, I get 0.0. I'm guessing that's where the digits afterwards are left off.