# Rounding in Java using Math.random()

Tags: java, math, random

Suppose I write

```
System.out.println (Math.random()*5);
```

then one would obtain and output of x in [0, 4.9...]. But upon casting it as an integer, the result I continuously see (in my course) is [0, 4]. My question is how we are defining the rounding function; I am familiar with the floor function, and the floor of 4.9... is precisely 5 due to there existing no epsilon larger than zero satisfying the output x existing in some epsilon neighborhood; i.e., the equality 4.9... = 5 suffices and because the floor of an integer is that integer, the result would be 5.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `floor(4.9);` is 4.  `(int)4.9;` is 4.

Comment: You are not rounding by casting to an integer. You are truncating.

Comment: This is computer floating point math, not mathematical continuous floating point math.

Comment: @geocodezip floor(4.9...) repeating decimal is 5.

Comment: @NomadMaker what is the difference between the two? I am merely looking for a precise definition

Comment: And `Math.random()` doesn't round at all. And 4.9999 recurring can't be represented exactly, and the nearest representation is probably already 5.0.

Comment: the largest value you should be able to get is: `0x13ffffffffffff * 2**-50`.  the decimal expansion of this has 15 `9`s, which seems like a finite number to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a new answer to address questions raised in comments. The output of `Math.random()` is in the range [0,1). The result will be a number strictly less than 1, so `Math.random()*5` will give a result in the range [0,5), that is a number strictly less than 5. Since casting truncates, that means that your results will be in the integer set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} with (approximately) equal probabilities for each of the five values.

[Java: Math.random() Max Value (double just less than 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736885/java-math-random-max-value-double-just-less-than-1) has some more details on the math of the exact values that are possible with `Math.random()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast to int like this

```
int i = (int) 4.9;
```

JVM will simply drop decimal places and you will get value 4 assigned to the variable. It is not rounding it is truncating,

Comment: 4.99... repeating is what I am asking, not 4.9.

Comment: The floor of 4.99 repeating is 5. You can verify with Wolfram alpha

Comment: @user143 In all the computer libraries I know of, the floor of 4.99 repeating is 4. Again, computer math is not the same as theoretical math, expect in such systems as Wolfram.

Comment: @NomadMaker I do not know how one differentiates between the two; the floor function is not theoretical, nor is the equality of 4.9... = 5. How does one define the floor function in computer math?

Comment: As other people have said, in computer libraries, floor just truncates. This happens because there is no way to write 4.99 infinitely repeating.

Comment: No, it happens because `floor()` is *supposed* to truncate. Nothing to do with recurrng decimal places.

Comment: @NomadMaker Well, one could devise a representation of repeating decimals using some other number representation, e.g. geometric series. A computer algebra system could do it. But specifically to answer OP's question, a `double` in Java is actually a rational number, and whether it's less, equal, or greater than 4 is unambiguous.

Comment: @user143 A web search for IEEE 754 will turn up the resources you need. Java and other languages represent decimal numbers as rational approximations of the form (2^exponent) times (nnnnn) where nnnnn are the significant bits and 2^exponent is a scaling factor. There are many other representations, but IEEE 754 is built into hardware, so it is the default. Java `float` and `double` are 32 and 64 bit versions of that. There are other, software-only number representations for Java, such as BigDecimal and BigInteger, and many other representations for other languages.